# Angular Filtering a List

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my code, I'M trying to filter a list of elements when an option is selected from a combobox. My code is below. Right now, the code doesn't have any errors, but I couldn't succeed on filtering the list. What should I do?

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex fxFlex.gt-sm="50" class="pr-4">
                                <mat-label>Document Type</mat-label>
                                <mat-select [(ngModel)]="sourceType" (ngModelChange)="searchTransaction()">
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let dp of sourceTypeList" [value]="dp">
                                        {{dp.Name}}
                                    </mat-option>
                                </mat-select>
                            </mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
     sourceTypeList: IBasicModel[];
     sourceType: IBasicModel;
    stockTransactionList: IStockTransaction[] = [];

    searchTransaction() {
            if (this.stockTransactionList && this.stockTransactionList.length > 0) {
                let stockTransactionSearchData: IStockTransaction[] = [
                    ...this.stockTransactionList,
                ];
//FILTER FOR SOURCE TYPE
                if(this.sourceType){
                    stockTransactionSearchData = stockTransactionSearchData.filter((x) => x.SourceType.Id);
                }
    
                //Default
                this.dataSourceStockTransactions.data = [...stockTransactionSearchData,];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the html (the *ngFor part). It seems that you have messed the bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not comparing the selected type in the filter that you have implemented.

I created an example trying to replicate your case on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-wrz1xd?file=src/app/app.component.ts), you'll find the complete example there.

```js
  sourceTypeList: IBasicModel[] = [
    { id: 1, category: 'finance' },
    { id: 2, category: 'housing' }
  ];
  sourceType: IBasicModel;
  stockTransactionList: IStockTransaction[] = [
    { id: 1, info: 'tr1', sourceType: { id: 1, category: 'finance' } },
    { id: 2, info: 'tr2', sourceType: { id: 2, category: 'housing' } },
    { id: 1, info: 'tr3', sourceType: { id: 1, category: 'finance' } },
    { id: 2, info: 'tr4', sourceType: { id: 2, category: 'housing' } },
    { id: 1, info: 'tr5', sourceType: { id: 1, category: 'finance' } },
    { id: 2, info: 'tr6', sourceType: { id: 2, category: 'housing' } }
  ];

 //FILTER FOR SOURCE TYPE
      if (this.sourceType) {
        stockTransactionSearchData = stockTransactionSearchData.filter(
          x => x.sourceType.id === this.sourceType.id // the comparison 
        );
      }
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `FormControl` and subscribe to valueChanges.

```js
sourceTypeControl = new FormControl('');

constructor() {
  this.sourceTypeControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    // ...
    console.log(value);
    if (value) {
      // stockTransactionSearchData = stockTransactionSearchData.filter((x) => x.SourceType.Id);
    }
  })
  }
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Document Type</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="sourceTypeControl">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let dp of sourceTypeList" [value]="dp">
      {{dp.Name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I've created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vryfhs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) which you'll have to adapt for your specific behavior.

Comment: @RocketMonkey Please see the Stackblitz I provided